# Alert message or pop up message Displayed to the user when the Session Expires...Can any one tell me the code for this?

Tags: asp.net

Code to Display a Pop up Message or alert message to user before Session Expires...and before it redirects to Login  page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
      this.GetType(),
      Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
      string.Format("alert('{0}');window.location.href = 'default.aspx'", 
        message.Replace("'", @"\'").Replace("\n", "\\n").Replace("\r", "\\r")),
        true);
```